# JAVA LDAP - all data retrieval

Tags: java, ldap, jndi

My *LDAP* has persons entry of more than *100 thousand* but when i enter the search query i just *receive 2000* entries.

```
SearchControls constraints = new SearchControls();
            constraints.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
            constraints.setCountLimit(1);//pageSize
            NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> results = ctx.search("DC=YourDomain,DC=com", filterQuery, constraints);
            while (results != null && results.hasMore()) {
                person = new Person();
                Attributes attrs = ((SearchResult) results.next()).getAttributes();
                person.setEmail(attrs.get("email").toString());
                person.setEmployee_id(attrs.get("employee_id").toString());
                person.setGuid(attrs.get("guid").toString());
                person.setId(Integer.parseInt(attrs.get("id").toString()));
                person.setName(attrs.get("name").toString());
                person.setPhone(attrs.get("phone").toString());
                person.setPpid(attrs.get("ppid").toString());
                result.add(person);
            }
```

Exception thrown -

```
javax.naming.SizeLimitExceededException: [LDAP: error code 4 - Sizelimit Exceeded];
```

Comment: `results` cannot possibly be null at the point you are testing it.

Answer (score 0):

`javax.naming.SizeLimitExceededException` means you have exceed a size related limit, that can set by you in search options, or that can be set by LDAP implementation.

You have specified `constraints.setCountLimit(1);` which indicates that you are asking only for one result (*see javadoc [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/naming/directory/SearchControls.html#setCountLimit(long))*). A value of `0` means no limit on objects retrieval.

I don't know why it is retrieving 2000 entries, but you can try to put `0` and see if it works, other case, you will have to see LDAP server configuration, because it can be ignoring `constraints.setCountLimit` option.

Answer (score 0):

Either Java or more probably the server is limiting the number of search results you can retrieve at a time.

You need to look into the [paged results control](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/naming/ldap/PagedResultsControl.html).

There is no way you are going to be able to retrieve all 100,000 entries in a single operation, and there is a significant risk that they won't all fit into memory anyway. There is no way a properly configured server should let you even try, anyway.